# Find Worst Case complexity of below algorithm

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, complexity-theory

I am trying to find the worst case complexity of algorithm below. The alogorithm finds the location LOC1 pf the largest element and the location LOC2 of the second largest element in an array DATA with n > 1 elements. I am taking complexity as the number of comparisopns during the execution of the algorithm,

```
FIND(DATA, N, LOC1, LOC2)

    1. Set FIRST = DATA[1], SECOND = DATA[2], LOC = 1, LOC2 = 2.

    2. IF FIRST < SECOND then:
    a. Interchange FIRST and SECOND.
    b. Set LOC1 = 2 and LOC2 = 1.
    [End of If structure.]

    3. Repeat for  K= 3 to N:
    If FIRST < DATA[K], then:
    a. Set SECOND = FIRST and FIRST = DATA[k].
    b. Set LOC2 = LOC1 and LOC2 = K.
    Else if SECOND < DATA[K], then:
        Set SECOND = DATA[K] and LOC2 = K.

    [End of loop.]

    4. Return
```

I am not not able to figure out how to find the complexity of above program since the number of comparisons will depend upon how the elements in the array are arranged. For the worst case scenario the else condition where the SECOND element is compared against DATA[K] should also be executed for the maximum number of times. But then there can be many cases depending upon the elements of the DATA array.

Thanx,

Regards

tek3

Comment: This question is more appropriate for http://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The worst case scenario is when step 3 always performs two comparisons for all n-2 iterations. So, step 2 has one comparison and step 3 has 2*(n-2) comparisons.

Comment: yes sir you are indeed correct. I dont know why I got so confused in this problem. Thanx a lot for your answer sir.